# Create tar into stdout on Ubunutu 16

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tar

`tar` cannot write to standard output on Ubuntu 16:

```
prod ~    $ cat /etc/os-release  | grep -i version
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial

prod ~    $ tar -cf - tmp
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Let's try on CentOS7:

```
[root@drft068 ~]# tar -cf - /tmp
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /tmp/mongodb-27018.sock: socket ignored
tar: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock: socket ignored
tmp/00017770000000000000000000000000131574472010
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: This might help: `tar -cf - tmp | cat`

Comment: @Cyrus This did help. What's explanation?

Comment: `tar` noticed that its `stdout` is connected to a terminal, thus refused to clutter it with its binary output. `cat` has no provisions for this. Redirecting `tar`'s output to `cat` thus connects the former's `stdout` to something not a terminal and `cat` doesn't care.

Comment: @Kamajii Why does tar on Ubuntu care about binary outout to terminal while on CentOS does not?

Comment: Probably because Ubuntu's version of `tar` has been patched to do so and CentOS' version hasn't. I'm not sure if this is included in upstream `tar` versions or if it's an Ubuntu specific patch. In the former case, compare the versions of the `tar` you're using. Maybe it's not even GNU `tar`...

Answer (score 14):

To have a proper SO answer here, I condensed @Kamajii and @Cyrus comments to the questions (please consider doing that yourselves ...).

`tar` notices that stdout will end up on a terminal. Besides the output is binary and thus not really readable for humans it is also a [security risk](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/can-cat-ing-a-file-be-a-potential-security-risk).

As soon as you redirect stdout of the `tar` process, it will work. One example given involves `cat`, which doesnt care if you give it a binary blob. Thus

`tar -cf - tmp | cat`

will display the binary stuff. Otherwise `tar -cf - tmp > mytmp.tar` is probably closer than what you want to use (although for this example a `tar -cf mytmp.tar tmp` would have been the typical call).

Comment: `tar -c tmp | cat` does the same, no need f option

Comment: @Alex Thanks for pointing that out! I guess your comment is true for 99% of the cases. According to my tars manpage, behaviour depends on the `TAPE` (yeah!) environment variable + compiled-in defaults. So, I guess for a SA answer its good to keep the `-f`, so that people on obscurer *nixes can also copy-paste the comannd.